# Theorem about complete graphs without intersections

Tags: graph-theory

I was solving the exercises in Balakrishnan´s *Introductory Discrete Mathematics* (great book btw), especifically the first chapter on *graph theory.* Then i stumbled upon an exercise in which we are asked to draw a complete 4-vertice graph with no intersections, then a complete 5-vertice one, and then analize the fundamental difference between them. Drawing the first one isn´t that difficult, but when i went to do the 5-vertice one, i couldn´t do it without intersecting edges. Then i tried with 6 and 7 vertices and it only got worse, so a natural conjecture to make would be that:

#### **There are no complete, non-intersecting graphs with more than 4 vertices**.

I´d like to know:

**1**. *If this is a known theorem, and if it is, who first proved it and how?*
**2**. *If it is not known, how could i attack such a conjecture in an effective way?*

Comment: It is a well-known theorem.

Comment: It has been known for at least 80 years, maybe much more. Are you familiar with Euler's $v-e+f=2$ formula? That's an important part of one way to prove it.

Comment: It should be easy to see that it can "only get worse" when you try complete graphs with more vertices: If you had a planar drawing of $K_6$, you could delete one of the vertices and all edges ajacent to it, and what's left would be a planar drawing of $K_5$.